# Why 'Authorization Required' is coming on wordpress login

Tags: htaccess, 404-error, authentication

When i try to login to my WordPress blog admin why this pop up error come ..

```
"Authorization Required" 
http://stpatrickscollege.edu.pk/wp-login.php
```

Comment: All i see is a login page, which is what should be there.

Comment: Some host providors are blocking access to `wp-login.php` because of large distributed brute force attacks against WordPress sites, see for example: http://thehackernews.com/2013/04/massive-brute-force-attack-targets.html This might have been the reason in your case.

Answer (score 2):

*"Authorization Required"* message is from the Apache world.

Looks like you have set the [basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) in apache for the login page. This is simply indicated by the "pop-up" type of the error.